# cover which is not Galois cover

Tags: algebraic-topology, galois-theory, covering-spaces

I couldn't find any example of cover which is not Galois.

The definition is following:
A cover $p:Y\rightarrow X$ is said to be $Galois$ if $Y$ is connected and the induced map $\bar{p}:Aut(Y|X)\setminus Y\rightarrow X$ is a homeomorphism.

I tried to make some example by using cover of graph $S_1 \vee S_1$, but it didn't work.

Is there simple answer about my question?

Comment: Take a non-connected cover? I guess it depends on your definition of covering space.

Comment: I try to find connected cover Y->X.

Comment: Does [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/337219/4280) help?

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/28465/4280) seems to provide an example. I'm no expert, so I'll refrain from further comment on this.

Comment: This should be similar to finding a non-Galois field extension. Just start with a Galois extension, and use a non-normal subgroup of the Galois group.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Forgive my paint art.

[image]

This is a degree 3 cover of $S^1\vee S^1$ (below). The projection map $p$ every red segment or loop to the red loop respecting the given orientation, and similarly for green. You can see it is indeed a cover. Now, I claim that this cover is non Galois. In fact, the deck-automorphism group is trivial. To see this, note that it acts on the black dots. But these black dots are very different from each other : the top one has a single green loop and two red segments out of him, the middle one has two red segments and two green segments, and the bottom one has a single red loop and two green segments. Thus every deck automorphism should preserve these three dots. It follows that every deck automorphism is the identity.